# What do you call the digital displays that show the stations inside subway trains?

Tags: phrase-request, colloquial-language

I'm talking about this:

[image]

The text in the photo says "digital voice announcement."  But I wonder if there's another way of referring to this piece of technology. Something like digital announcement or station announcement? Without putting emphasis in the sound part?

(Note: I'm not looking for a technical term, just a common one, or one that everyone would understand.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These things are called passenger information displays (or display systems) in most English speaking countries, including Australia (where Hurlstone Park is), Britain and the USA, where they have been used in new subway and main line rolling stock (equipment in USA) since the 1990s. The actual piece of technology in the picture is called a "dot matrix display". A lot of such systems don't use displays like in the picture, they have LCD screens (like a flat screen TV or monitor) and people just call those 'screens' or maybe "information screens". They are found in trains and buses, at stations, bus stops, airports, etc.

[Passenger Information system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_information_system)

Comment: Thanks. So the shortest, most common way of referring to them is "display system?"

Comment: Yes, but you can just say "display". The display at the end of the carriage says the next station is Hurlstone Park.

Comment: And you'd say "car" instead of "carriage" in the US.

Comment: In the UK you say "carriage" or "coach" about main line passenger train vehicles and "car" for those on the London Underground.

Comment: We're "train car", "subway car".

Comment: @Michael Harvey I have  always used the term ' carriage' for the London Underground. Although TFL uses both in this description of its various rolling stock is places.https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/about-tfl/what-we-do/london-underground/rolling-stock

Comment: The Underground depot staff, and rail buffs, call them cars. It all goes back to Charles Tyson Yerkes apparently.

Comment: @Michael Harvey yes but everyone else, including TFL in some cases, call them carriages.

Comment: TfL is not consistent: they say on the same page that sub-surface S7 stock "has 7 carriages" but also that 1992 tube stock (Central + Waterloo and City) has "twin sliding doors, plus one single door at each end of each car". Later on 1973 tube stock has "carriages" again. [Rolling stock (TfL)](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/about-tfl/what-we-do/london-underground/rolling-stock). The ads inside train vehicles are called "car cards", and the line diagrams are called "car line diagrams (CLDs)":  [Car Line Diagrams (TfL)](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/publications-and-reports/car-line-diagrams)

Comment: Yes and that's exactly what I said in my original comment TFL use both, but if you look at various articles in the papers such as The London Evening Standard  or the Metro the standard term by common usage is carriages. There were many articles for example this summer on how hot the carriages were in the heatwave. A few technical people use the term car, but it's similar to if people asked how much I weighed and I gave an answer in Newtons rather than Stones, it's correct but many people would just look blankly at me.

Comment: I'm one of those people who get cross if a newspaper calls a multiple unit an 'engine' or when the BBC uses a picture of a BR Southern Region multiple unit to accompany any story about railways. I have to remember that normals don't care.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could call that a **marquee**.  I've never heard anyone refer to it by name, though in the US that sort of display is a fairly recent innovation. Here's [someone complaining back in 2010](https://www.cooper.com/journal/2010/10/when_and_where_back_to_basics) about the lack of such devices in San Francisco trains.